# PHP regex to add #ErrorLog with special character

Tags: php, regex

i have to add "#ErrorLog" to this line

```
$directivesRegex = '#^ *(ServerAlias|ServerAdmin|DocumentRoot|ServerName|CustomLog) +(.+)$#im';
```

how can i add it to the code ?

Comment: What's not working in your attempt?

Comment: when i try to add it like this when i try to add like this , i have an error.
   $directivesRegex = '#^ *(ServerAlias|ServerAdmin|DocumentRoot|ServerName|#ErrorLog|CustomLog) +(.+)$#im';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salmen,

You are using # as a delimiter, so you either need to escape the # in the regex, or to change the delimiter. Just changing the delimiter in your code with a tilde (~):

```
$directivesRegex = '~^ *(ServerAlias|ServerAdmin|DocumentRoot|ServerName|#ErrorLog|CustomLog) +(.+)$~im';
```

Comment: @Salmen Fantastic. If the answer was correct, can you please remember to accept it and / or upvote it by clicking on the left—that is how the site's reputation works. Thanks!

Comment: @Salmen Hey did you realize that adding \ was suggested in my answer as one of the ways to handle the problem? `you either need to escape the # in the regex...` I haven't heard from you.